# How do I configure a cable net?

Tags: 11.10, internet, pppoe, dsl

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 at home, I have cable net INTERNET connection.

In windows I am able to connect by dial-up connection.

How do I configure it in Ubuntu 11.10?

Log file attached below

[image: Plog error]

I am trying from 5 days please help me

Sorry i have to post this from windows xp.

Comment: How to i close the question i got the solution on my own

Comment: Post the solution as an answer below (click the Answer Your Question button) as it might be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of try formatting the machine and reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 and carried out the following steps

1. Edit the network connection go DSL option and clicked the add option
2. Put the required user name and password and kept the service name blank
3. in PPP setting i removed all authentication option saved and restarted the Ubuntu.
4. Still it was not working the i kept Chap option tick mark removed all other and restarted.
5. Still it was not not working then i again tick all the option and it was working.

Remember: Tick the Connect automatically option on in both wired and dsl tab

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need any other program than network manager(installed by default in ubuntu). Just click on the network icon, edit connections, DSL, Add. Then fill in the username and password fields (leave the Service field empty). Click on Save. Close the Network Connections window and the connection should appear when you click on the Network icon from the task bar(with the name DSL Connection 1 or the name you gave it). If it does not appear, just reboot. The connection should be there.
Cheers!

Comment: i tried this not working

Answer (score 0):

To Solve your problem, I have two options, both are working the same. Whichever you like install it. It's easy to configure and use.

You can find the details as bellow.

1 ]

GNOME PPP is an easy to use graphical dialup connection configuring and dialing tool with system tray icon support.

It uses GNOME/GTK+ for its graphical interface and integrates well in GNOME desktop environment, but it can be used in other environments.

It also uses WvDial dialer as its backend, providing simple configuration via config files. You can also use plain wvdial if you don't have X running.

Homepage: http://www.gnome-ppp.org/

2]

KPPP is a modem dialer for connecting to a dial-up Internet Service Provider. It displays statistics and accounting information to help users keep track of connection costs.

This package is part of the KDE 4 networking module.

You can find both Apppication on Ubuntu Software Center. both have Graphical Environment. So, you can easily configure and dial-up.

Comment: Was there a technical reason for the down-vote here?

Comment: It work only the modem and usb connection,but not with ethernet